# Convert string to float64 in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe **(df)** like the following

[image]

I'm trying to convert the values in dataframe to int and float64 types.

```
df['poiid'] = df['poiid'].astype(int)
df['lng'] = df['lng'].astype('float64')
df['lat'] = df['lat'].astype('float64')
```

The code above does not work properly for float64, it only takes **6** decimal values after comma for **lng** and **lat** attributes. ( Please see the Output below)

Output

[image]

My expectation is **10 digits** after the comma

**my expectation output:**

```
8904  -94.6074986458, 39.0523183095

...
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a limit in the displayed precision, while the dataframe actually holds what you expect?

Comment: what you see is just the default string representation with 6 decimal places, the number may have more decimal places

Comment: just try `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.10f}'.format`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is just the default string representation with 6 decimal places. You can set you own [display format option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options) with

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.10f}'.format
```

to show 10 places.
Alternatively you can confirm the number if you look at the result of say `df.loc[1,'lng']`.

To set the option only temporarily you can use an [option context](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html):

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:.10f}'.format):
    print(df)
```